# Make gridster.js tiles stick in specific grid positions (snap to grid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

is there any way to make Gridster.js tile(s) stick, that is not move up vertically to fill empty space. Kind of like the way a layout program with snap-to-grid turned on works...

Comment: you can use [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) as an alternative. It already have Snap to Grid functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Use this fork https://github.com/dsmorse/gridster.js with

```
shift_widgets_up: false
```

option.

See demo : http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/sticky-postion.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried packery? http://packery.metafizzy.co/
This library has many drag and drop features.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in the following prototype from my team:  https://github.com/ibmjstart/gridplumb

Specifically, the modifications to grister can be found at https://github.com/ibmjstart/gridplumb/blob/master/src/extend-gridster.js

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not directly linked to gridster but to one of its fork : gridstack. I post this answer as I found this topic while searching for this functionality in gridstack.

So in gridstack solution is to put this property in grid options :

```
float:true
```