# Way to create empty space in gridster js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grid, gridster

I am doing project in jquery to display the bus map as rows and columns. For that I am using *gridster.js* to display the seat arrangement. I am having the piece of following code

```
$(".gridster ul", xxxMapContainerST).each(function(){ 
            var gridster =$(this).gridster({ 
                widget_margins : [ 1, 1 ], 
                widget_base_dimensions : [ 30, 30 ], 
                draggable : false, 
                avoid_overlapped_widgets : false, 
                extra_rows : 0, 
                extra_cols : 0, 
                resize:false                                         
            }).data('gridster').disable(); 
        });
```

Here the problem arise is when I want to display empty seats i.e not a cornered seats. **The empty seat position was filled by the adjacent seats (filled by vertically down position seats). It causes severe misalignment.** I have googled . No obvious solution found. Anyone kindly do some remedy for this problem.

Below link raises the same question, yet no answer found

[Make gridster.js tiles stick in specific grid positions (snap to grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393704/make-gridster-js-tiles-stick-in-specific-grid-positions-snap-to-grid)

Comment: Bored of looking this question, kindly anyone do me favour

Answer (score 1):

I was going thru something like same. May be I am answering it way too late! 
But the demo link you have mentioned here is using a better 'version' of Gridster.

E.g. , the package I have downloaded from gridster's official page is v0.5.6 - 2014-09-25

and the one which consists of demo is - v0.6.10 - 2015-05-31

If you still want to upgrade your app 
Following are the download links for CSS and JS 
JS : http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/dist/jquery.gridster.min.js
CSS : http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/dist/jquery.gridster.min.css